# C# - How can i color string if they start and end with the same number

Tags: c#, string, numbers, substring

As mentioned above i need to have a part of my string colored if they start and end with the same number.
Im a beginner and can't really figure it out, i have googled but haven't found any answers.

*EDIT*
To clarify, i need to print the whole string and not just the colored part.

```
string userInput = "29535123p48723487597645723645";
            //Console.WriteLine(userInput);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Char.IsDigit(userInput[i]))
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < userInput.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (userInput[i] == userInput[j])
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            Console.WriteLine(userInput.Substring(i, j - i + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (!Char.IsDigit(userInput[j]))
                        {

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: How do you define "start and end with the same number"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Which part must be colored? whats the rule to follow for that?

Comment: Do you mean like "29abc29" and then the "29"s should be green?

Comment: For example if the string would contain "2432a302" the part that would be green is "2432" but "a302" would be white
For the string i used "29535123p48723487597645723645" the green colored bits would be "2953512" "535" "35123" "487234" "872348" and so on.
The problem im having is with the code that i wrote it only prints out the colored bits while i need the whole string.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me _at all_.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an assignement that i need to get done, i have no idea what to do

Comment: Ahhhh, now I get it .... all _substrings_ that are numerical-only and start and end on the same number....

Comment: Yes, i have no idea how to print all the substrings together with the string

Comment: I am guessing, you are supposed to print each "hit" at a time, so you can color them in the original string. So if you have 5 hits, you'd have 5 lines of the original string, where you color a different hit in each line? Makes sense?

Comment: Yes exactly, do you have any tips on how to write that code?

Comment: To outline the strategy: I'd make a function, that takes a string and two indices, which prints the string , coloring it from startindex to endindex. Then you need to find an algorithm to detect the desired substrings and collect their first and last index. Then you only have to iterate the latter passing the arguments to the former ...

Comment: Thanks, i did actually start on that but didn't know where to go from there. Ill try to get it working. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 2):

I gave it a quick try. I'll try and explain in comments:

```
class Program
{
    // input given in Question by OP
    public static string testinput = "29535123p48723487597645723645";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessString(testinput);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ProcessString(string input)
    {
        // We'll have one index running from start of the string
        for (int fromStart = 0; fromStart < input.Length - 1; fromStart++)
        {
        // and another one running from the end
            for (int fromEnd = input.Length - 1; fromEnd > fromStart; fromEnd--)
            {
                // If both match, check if the found substring is all-digits
                if (input[fromStart] == input[fromEnd])
                {
                    if( input.Substring(fromStart, fromEnd-fromStart).IsNumCharOnly() )
                        PrintResult(testinput, fromStart, fromEnd);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintResult(string original, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        // remember the original fg-color
        var originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        // Print the part before the hit
        Console.Write(original.Substring(0, fromIndex));
        // change color
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        // print the hit
        Console.Write(original.Substring(fromIndex, toIndex-fromIndex +1));
        // change color back
        Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
        // print the rest, if there is something left
        if( toIndex < original.Length-1)
            Console.Write(original.Substring(toIndex+1));
        // add a newline in any case.
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

static class StringExtensions
{
    // Extensionmethod on string
    public static bool IsNumCharOnly(this string str)
    {
        // if any of the string's chars is outside '0'-'9' chars, 
        // return false, otherwise return true
        return !str.Any(c => c < '0' || c > '9');
    }
}
```

Now, what does it do?

We go through the string from start and end until we find a match.
Then we check if the string delimited by the to indices contains a non-digit.
If so, we ignore the candidate, else we have a winner and print it.

```
29535123p48723487597645723645
^                           ^ = No
^                          ^  = No
^                         ^   = No
^                        ^    = No
^                       ^     = YES !!
=> Candidate : 29535123p4872348759764572 contains "p" => meh
29535123p48723487597645723645
^                      ^      = No
... // Some more false positives, we ignore ...
29535123p48723487597645723645
^     ^                       = YES !!
=> Candidate : 2953512 => PRINT!
...
29535123p48723487597645723645
^^                            = No
// Next OUTER loop iteration:
29535123p48723487597645723645
 ^                          ^ = No
... and so on
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT: C# 8

With access to the ["Range"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) notation it's even a little more readable:

```
if( input[fromStart..fromEnd].IsNumCharOnly() )
```

Comment: Wow.. Absolutely amazing man, thank you very much. I tested the code and it works perfectly, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @Arcee Make sure you understand it, though. Some parts, you could play around with. For example: in the string extension, I could have used `Char.IsDigit`. I think one thing to take away is: separate concerns. Find your result => Algo's part. Print the result => different page. Separating both, I can easily change how the result is displayed. And I can change the algorithm without breaking the display...

Comment: Yeah i noticed the Char.IsDigit thing, i will save the code and try to change a few things to learn and understand. Thanks again

Comment: What i don't understand is the extensionmethod, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: _"Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type."_ - [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: Basically, syntactic sugar. With this, I was able to create a function that can be called like `myString.IsDigitOnly()`. Instead of having a "usual" static function and call it like `IsDigitsOnly(myString)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
        String s1 = "1234567890";
        String s2 = "1234567891";

        changeColor(s1);
        changeColor(s2);


        
        void changeColor(String s)
        {
            char start = s[0];
            char end = s[s.Length-1];

            if (start == end)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write(s[0]);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                for (int i = 1; i < s.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(s[i]);
                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write(s[s.Length-1]);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
```